# Route prefix with resource controller - Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Route & Prefix has same name. I'm not able to get `ID` parameter of `{hotel}` which is empty as i mention below in image. What is the best way to use prefix and resource controller with same name?

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::namespace('Admin\Hotel')->prefix('hotels')->name('hotels.')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/', 'HotelController');
    Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomController');
    Route::resource('rooms/gallery', 'RoomGalleryController');
});
```

`php artisan route:list` for `Route::resource('/', 'HotelController')`

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Can you be a bit clearer, please?

Comment: same the question is not clear

Comment: `URI: http:example.com/admin/hotels` route group prefix name is `hotels` and my resource controller name is `hotels` as well. If prefix & resource controller name is same then what is the best way to use it?

Comment: @MartinBean i have updated the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it's because resource method will automaticly add the prefix and the named routes with the first parameter you give, `hotel` in your case.

So you can do something like this :

```
Route::namespace('Admin\Hotel')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('hotels', 'HotelController');
});
```

Or, you can remove group function and directly use resource method.

```
Route::resource('hotels', 'Admin\Hotel\HotelController');
```

Or,

```
Route::namespace('Admin\Hotel')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('hotels', 'HotelController');
    Route::prefix('hotels')->name('hotels.')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('gallery', 'HotelGalleryController');
        Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomController');
        Route::resource('rooms/gallery', 'RoomGalleryController');
    });
});
```

Comment: I got you if i remove the prefix from group i will have to add in named routes with the first parameter in each resource controller.

Comment: Yes or maybe you can have for exemple:

`Route::namespace('Admin\Hotel')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('hotels', 'HotelController');
    Route::prefix('hotels')->name('hotels.*')->group(function() {
         // other routes
    });
});`
because `resource` method will generate all for you.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes you want to keep it grouped, so the solution is to use the [parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters) method.

```
Route::namespace('Admin\Hotel')->prefix('hotels')->name('hotels.')->group(function () {
Route::resource('/', 'HotelController')->parameters(['' => 'hotel']);
Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomController');
Route::resource('rooms/gallery', 'RoomGalleryController');
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer for using resource within group of same name.

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer for this scenario

Answer (score 2):

I think using the group method would be better, try out this.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin\Hotel', 'prefix' => 'hotel'], function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: If i do this, `URI` will be `http:example.com/admin/hotel/hotels`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same scenario in mixing `Group` and `Resource` and I can't get the ID group (which in this case `Hotel`).

Here's how I did it in (Laravel 5.5):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'hotel/{hotel}'], function () {
    Route::resource('/', 'HotelController');
    Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomController');
    Route::resource('rooms/gallery', 'RoomGalleryController');
});
```